# Реализация оффлайн корзины на андроид

Tags: java, android, интернет-магазин

Всем добрый вечер.
Вопрос следующий: имеется файл с товарами, который я распарсиваю и создаю `ListView` меню с наименованиями товаров. Далее по клику на каждый `Item` должна формироваться корзина в которой будут храниться выбранные товары. Как лучше реализовать данную корзину и как правильнее будет хранить(и где?) выбранные товары? Может есть готовые примеры реализации интернет магазина(конкретно корзины) на андроид?
Буду рад любой помощи!
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Берите корзину и в Json строку, далее строку в SQLite или на крайняк в преференсы. Удобнее всего использовать [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) - типа:

```
Basket basket;
final Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString=gson.toJson(basket, Basket.class);
//далее пишите строку куда хотите в префы или в БД
```

Восстанавливаем корзину из Json строки таким макаром:

```
Basket basket=new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Basket.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList basket = new ArrayList<Item>();

onClick

basket.add(item);
```

Comment: Открыть приложение, набрать товаров, закрыть приложение, с грустью потерять.

Comment: ну так это уже 2й вопрос, можно писать в файл или сериализовать в преференсы